# Array Multiple Level Concat Selected Elements and Trim into One

Tags: typescript

For `book`, I want to loop each page, then each content element, trim leading and trailing space

```
var book = {
    "pages": [
        {
            "page": "1",
            "content": [" c1 ", "   c2 "],
            "note": ["n1", "n2"]
        },
        {
            "page": "2",
            "content": [" c3", "c4 "],
            "note": "any"
        },
        {
            "page": "3",
            "content": [" c5", " c6      "],
            "note": "any"
        }
    ],
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2
}
```

Produce output like

```
c1
c2
c3
c4
c5
c6
```

This code fails at producing `x`

```
var x = book.pages.forEach(cn =>
  {
    cn.content.map(c=> c.trim());  // this line test ok
  });
var y = x.join("\n");  // error: x is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `forEach`. It returns undefined. You should use `map` instead if you are expecting a return. But since you need to flatten your array, `flatMap`'s better suited:

```js
var book = {
    "pages": [
        {
            "page": "1",
            "content": [" c1 ", "   c2 "],
            "note": ["n1", "n2"]
        },
        {
            "page": "2",
            "content": [" c3", "c4 "],
            "note": "any"
        },
        {
            "page": "3",
            "content": [" c5", " c6      "],
            "note": "any"
        }
    ],
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2
}

let contents = book.pages.flatMap(page => page.content.map(x => x.trim()))
console.log(contents.join('\n'))
```

Comment: I was asking why `forEach` failed then notice you already provided an answer. Thank you